# Trying to stream to multiple RTMPs with tee throws: Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to stream one file to multiple rtmps. The following command streams ok to one endpoint:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop 10 -i input.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmps://x4t-myamsacc-usct.channel.media.azure.net:2935/live/x4t/x4t
```

This one does not:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -c copy -f tee "[f=flv]rtmps://x4t-myamsacc-usct.channel.media.azure.net:2935/live/x4t/x4t"
```

Throws this error:

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Once I can do it for one, I plan to do it for more. What could I be doing wrong? This is the console log:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-08-24-3477feb Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.101.100 / 58.101.100
  libavformat    58. 51.100 / 58. 51.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-07-13T08:13:55.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:15.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 368 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 239 kb/s, 30 fps, 30
tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-13T08:13:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 07/13/2018.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-13T08:13:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 07/13/2018.
Output #0, tee, to '[f=flv]rtmps://x4t-myamsacc-usct.channel.media.azure.net:2935/live/x4t/x4t':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [`-map` option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) when using `-f tee`. From the [tee muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee):

> Since the tee muxer does not represent any particular output format,
> ffmpeg cannot auto-select output streams. So all streams intended for
> output must be specified using `-map`.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f tee "[f=flv]rtmps://x4t-myamsacc-usct.channel.media.azure.net:2935/live/x4t/x4t"
```

Comment: It throws a different error using that: https://i.imgur.com/iY9BuU8.png

Comment: @user33276346 That's a completely different problem. Looks like a bug. Add `-vtag 7` as shown in [ffmpeg -f tee refuses to do anything useful](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/29633)